# How to increase cursor performance in sql

Tags: sql-server

i have used trigger for recalculation multiple data.
in trigger i have used cursor.in cursor i have used another sp's which is contain 1 more cursor.

so it's very slow for calculation of only 80 rows data. and it's take 20 second to calculate the data. so please give me any suggestion or solution for it quickly.

thanks

here is my trigger

```
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[tr_TransactionJournal_InsteadOfDelete]    Script Date: 12/23/2015 3:13:09 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_TransactionJournal_InsteadOfDelete]
    ON [dbo].[TransactionJournal]
    INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE
    @TxNum INT,
    @TxDate DATE

/*
    declare @TempDetailTable to figure out which ChartAcctCode & Item needs to be recalculated
*/
DECLARE @TempDetailTable TABLE (
    ChartAcctCode NVARCHAR(10),
    ItemCode NVARCHAR(10)
)

DECLARE @MyCursor_1 CURSOR
SET @MyCursor_1 = CURSOR FAST_FORWARD
FOR
    SELECT TxNum,TxDate FROM DELETED

OPEN @MyCursor_1
FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor_1
INTO @TxNum,@TxDate

WHILE @@fetch_status = 0 -- This is executed as long as the previous fetch succeeds.
BEGIN
------------------  

    BEGIN TRANSACTION
    INSERT INTO @TempDetailTable
    SELECT DISTINCT tjd.ChartAcctCode, tjd.ItemCode
    FROM dbo.TransactionJournalDetail AS tjd 
    WHERE (tjd.TxNum = @TxNum)-- AND    tjd.ItemCode IS NOT NULL
    COMMIT TRANSACTION

    /*
    Actually deleting FROM TxJournal & TxJournalDetail
    */
    DELETE FROM TransactionJournal WHERE TxNum=@TxNum

    /*
    Start Recalculating...
    */
    DECLARE @MyChartAcctCode NVARCHAR(10)
    DECLARE @MyItemCode NVARCHAR(10)

    DECLARE @MyCursor CURSOR
    /*
    1st Loop to RecalcQAV if Detail has any ChartAcctCode = "AINV"
    */
    SET @MyCursor = CURSOR FAST_FORWARD
    FOR
        SELECT ItemCode FROM @TempDetailTable WHERE ChartAcctCode = 'INV'

    OPEN @MyCursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor
    INTO @MyItemCode

    WHILE @@fetch_status = 0
    BEGIN

        EXEC RecalcQAV @MyItemCode, @TxDate;

    FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor
    INTO @MyItemCode

    END
    /*
    2nd Loop to RecalcAcctBalance if Detail has any ChartAcctCode = "AINV"
    */

    SET @MyCursor = CURSOR FAST_FORWARD
    FOR
        SELECT ChartAcctCode FROM @TempDetailTable

    OPEN @MyCursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor
    INTO @MyChartAcctCode

    WHILE @@fetch_status = 0
    BEGIN

        EXEC RecalcAcctBalance @MyChartAcctCode, @TxDate;

    FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor
    INTO @MyChartAcctCode

    END

    CLOSE @MyCursor;
    DEALLOCATE @MyCursor;

------------------
FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor_1
INTO @TxNum,@TxDate
END

CLOSE @MyCursor_1;
DEALLOCATE @MyCursor_1;
```

Comment: please provide code for `RecalcQAV` and `RecalcAcctBalance`

Comment: My suggestion is to find another way to do the job. You combine two things (triggers and cursors) that everyone should try to avoid. To me it is a time bomb waiting to explode. Take a look here http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/123074/sql-triggers-and-when-or-when-not-to-use-them

Comment: here is a my RecalQAV and RecalAcctBalance https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0L1I7NosKsgTGN5RzY1bTMyUjg

Comment: your link is protected... pls set it to public...

Comment: The best way to increase performance, is to not rely on `CURSOR`s or `TRIGGER`s. Find a set-based way of doing what you're supposed to do. If that cannot be done (should be rarely) then you're stuck with sub-performant tools.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0L1I7NosKsgTGN5RzY1bTMyUjg/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[RecalcAcctBalance]
(
    @ChartAcctCode NVARCHAR(10),
    @BeginDate DATE
)
AS BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @LastDate DATE
    SELECT @LastDate = MAX(tj.TxDate)
    FROM dbo.TransactionJournal AS tj
    JOIN dbo.TransactionJournalDetail AS tjd ON tj.TxNum = tjd.TxNum
    WHERE tj.TxDate < @BeginDate
        AND tjd.ChartAcctCode = @ChartAcctCode

    DECLARE @MyTable TABLE (
        AutoId INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
        TxDate DATE,
        TxDetailId INT
    )
    INSERT INTO @MyTable (TxDate, TxDetailId)
    SELECT tj.TxDate, tjd.AutoId
    FROM dbo.TransactionJournal AS tj
    JOIN dbo.TransactionJournalDetail AS tjd ON tj.TxNum = tjd.TxNum
    WHERE tj.TxDate >= ISNULL(@LastDate, @BeginDate)
        AND tjd.ChartAcctCode = @ChartAcctCode
    ORDER BY tj.TxDate, tj.SourceDocOrder, tjd.AutoId

    DECLARE
        @LastDateMaxId INT, 
        @TxDetailId INT,
        @LChartAcctBalance MONEY = 0

    IF @LastDate IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN

        SELECT @TxDetailId = TxDetailId
        FROM (
            SELECT TxDetailId, RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY AutoId DESC)
            FROM @MyTable
            WHERE TxDate = @LastDate
        ) t
        WHERE t.RowNum = 1

        SELECT @LChartAcctBalance = ISNULL(ChartAcctBalance, 0)
        FROM dbo.TransactionJournalDetail
        WHERE AutoId = @TxDetailId

    END

    ;WITH cte AS 
    (
        SELECT *, val = @LChartAcctBalance + SUM(Amount) OVER (ORDER BY AutoId)
        FROM dbo.TransactionJournalDetail
        WHERE AutoId IN (
                SELECT TxDetailId
                FROM @MyTable
                WHERE TxDate >= @BeginDate
            )  
    )
    UPDATE cte
    SET ChartAcctBalance = val

END
```

the second sp is too large for refactoring... anyway the main problem - business logic with processing by item...